Create multiple level yaml file with shiny
I would like to create a simple shiny app to let the user export a yaml file. Creating the structure of a yaml file can be tricky. When I want to use the selectInput to give the user multiple options it works when we only have that function. Here is some reproducible example:
library(shiny)
library(yaml)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Letters", "Select a letter:", LETTERS[1:4]),
  downloadButton("export_yaml", "Export yaml")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    list(test_yaml = setNames(list(TRUE), input$Letters))
  })
  
  output$export_yaml <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0('test_yaml', ".yaml")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      yaml_input <- as.yaml(data())
      cat(as.character(yaml_input), sep = "\n", file = file, append = TRUE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Output test_yaml.yaml:
test_yaml:
  A: yes

This is right, but when we add another option above the current function it returns an empty string as named value for the option. Here is the code:
library(shiny)
library(yaml)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Letters", "Select a letter:", LETTERS[1:4]),
  downloadButton("export_yaml", "Export yaml")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    list(test_yaml = list(test = TRUE), # Changed code
         setNames(list(TRUE), input$Letters))
  })
  
  output$export_yaml <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0('test_yaml', ".yaml")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      yaml_input <- as.yaml(data())
      cat(as.character(yaml_input), sep = "\n", file = file, append = TRUE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Output test_yaml.yaml:
test_yaml:
  test: yes
'':
  A: yes

This is not my expected output, It should be like this:
test_yaml:
  test: yes
  A: yes

Since we just give another input option and not a new nested name. So I was wondering how we could create such yaml structure?

Have you considered ymlthis?  it's not perfect, but it's a start...

The problem originates in your data() object from the way you are structuring the lists. For example switching it to this gives your desired output:
  data <- reactive({
    yaml <- list(test_yaml = list(test = TRUE))
    yaml$test_yaml[[input$Letters]] <- TRUE
    yaml
  })

That gives this structure:
$test_yaml
$test_yaml$test
[1] TRUE

$test_yaml$A
[1] TRUE

Whereas before you had:
$test_yaml
$test_yaml$test
[1] TRUE


[[2]]
[[2]]$A
[1] TRUE

